# How to add an specific action button in views?

Tags: views, entities, console

Is there any way to add a specific action button in view module for an entity I've created programmatically.

More specifically, I want to make a search of my entity in view, and having beside each result of the entity an action button .  Currently,  we can configure 'delete/edit' button. I want to add a specific one.

PS: I'm using Drupal 8 and i created my module an entity with drupal console.

Comment: What is this button will do?

Comment: it will increment the value of a field  in the entity row concerned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution I found for my problem:
Let say that my entity is named **Entity**.
I created a new operation in my controller implementing my business logic ,  say we'll call it **operation_name**.
Then, in my **EntityListBuilder.php** , I surcharged the operation getDefaultOperations, specifying the name of my operation, the url and title :

 `public function getDefaultOperations(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $operations = parent::getDefaultOperations($entity);
    $operations['operation_name'] = array(
        'title' => $this->t('operation_title'),
        'weight' => 30,
        'url' => new Url('url',array(
          'medecin' => $entity->id(),
          )
        )
      );
      return  $operations;
    }`

Back to my view configuration: In adding fields section I will add "Action link" , we will notice that the operation "operation_name" was add to the others (edit and delete).

Comment: These steps are more described in french in this link [Ces étapes sont décrites plus amplement et en français dans le lien suivant ]:https://mydrupalworld.wordpress.com/2017/12/06/ajouter-un-bouton-daction-personnalise-dans-views/